Has the name Vasudeva वासुदेव been used for Vishnu before the Krishna avatara?
Krishna is Vasudeva for two reasons
(1) His father is Vasudeva वसुदेव (short "a")
(2) In-dwelling spirit.
Looking for Vishnu or his Avataras before the Krishna incarnation being called "Vasudeva".
Not looking for any references from Pancharatra Agamas.

Vāsudeva(वासुदेव) and Vasudeva(वसुदेव) are entirely different terms.  Vasudeva(वसुदेव) is Sri Krishna's father whereas Vāsudeva(वासुदेव) is Paradevatha (परदेवता) Whose abode is Parmapadam(परमपदम).

Your answer can be found in the Bāla Kānda of the Vālmīki Rāmayana, which, unless you consider it too be an interpolation, is fairly valid proof:

To whom this Mother Earth belongs in all her entirety, he is that prescient Vasudeva, and she is also the consort of that Maadhava, and that Vishnu eternally props up Mother Earth. Hence, that reverential Vishnu donning the semblance of Sage Kapila will burn down the sons of emperor Sagara to ashes in a fire of fury. [1.40.2-3]

This verse is of Brahma telling the gods prophetically about the famous episode of the 60,000 sons of King Sagara being incinerated by Kapila, an avatāra of Vishnu. It is Kapila who is called 'Vāsudeva' in this verse.

From the Mahanarayana upanishad

naaraayanaaya vidmahe vaasudevaaya dheemahi . tanno vishnuh' prachodayaat .. 29..


That is just a formulaic utterance and has probably been written AFTER Krishna's birth. @estimator

Thirupārkadal(திருப்பாற்கடல்/Ocean of Milk) is abode of Bagavān Vishnu whereas Vāsudeva(वासुदेव) is Paradevatha (परदेवता) Whose abode is Parmapadam(परमपदम) which is the  destination of those who have attained Moksha in accordance with Vaishnavism.
So even before Sri Krishna Avatāra (which took place in Dwāpara Yugam), that is in Krita and Treta Yugas too, the two entities Vāsudeva and Vishnu have been distinct and existed.

Vāsudeva(वासुदेव) and Vasudeva(वसुदेव) are entirely different names.
Vasudeva(वसुदेव) is Sri Krishna's father whereas Vāsudeva(वासुदेव) is
Paradevatha (परदेवता/Supreme Brahman) Whose abode is Parmapadam(परमपदम).

